# Creating a FB App using java on android

Tags: java, android, facebook, sdk

I'd need some help on this topic, so basically i've been reading a lot on the internet and have downloaded the sample from https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/ which when used their sample, it works but then after fiddling it for the pass few days, i'm lost again.

1. so basically, what i need is to register my app on fb then;
2. design the app and create it on android;

then comes the question, do i need still need the canvas on fb which will use php as well or is that a totally different thing?

my idea is to actually use the app that will retrieve or update my group's wall straight from the app. so basically what should i do, been lost but I'm willing to learn! just need someone to guide me :(

Answer (score 0):

> so basically, what i need is to
>   register my app on fb then;

Look at Facebook [Authentication](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) Documentation, it clearly states:

> [Register your application](http://developers.facebook.com/setup/) to get an
>   app ID and secret. Your Facebook app
>   ID is your client_id and your Facebook
>   application secret is your
>   client_secret.

The `client_id` and `client_secret` Facebook is referring about, is for your application to use [OAuth 2](http://oauth.net/2/) authorization protocol.

> design the app and create it on
>   android;

You will have to follow the registration requirements (e.g. application name, logo, url to default homepage, etc.) and use the Facebook Android SDK to integrate your application to Facebook.

In essence, you **must** register your application.

Comment: The Elite Gentleman; i think i've done that already but now it's more towards AFTER the login part. that part is purely by my design and coding is that correct? is there anyway that will help beginners like me learn :( but thanx for replying to me it's been hard to get answers nowadays

Comment: @eddy, so do you have the `access_token` after the login?

Comment: yes i believe i do:) my plan is after login in, it'd go straight to my group's page but i don't see how i can redirect it there

Comment: actually Elit Gentleman; from the sample from the github, i don't think i have the access_token :S

Comment: you only have an `access_token` only when you have completed the **oauth** authentication process as showed by Facebook and OAuth (I gave the link above). The Access Token is crucial for accessing Facebook.

Comment: The Elite Gentleman; the link you have given me has lead me to another link http://restfb.com/ but after reading and going through it seems like the example is useable but to some extent that some editing has to be done as well. I have registered the application, but I think i'd need to learn up more on the access token first before i can actually move on. hmm more hiccups really :(

Comment: The Elite Gentleman. may i be blunt and ask that, following  http://www.richardnichols.net/2010/06/implementing-facebook-oauth-2-0-authentication-in-java/ 's guide i think i have understand it but using the github example, can it be implemented? and am i wrong to have the idea that if what i need is a shortcut that goes straight to my group's page that is like a webview shortcut i don't need to the OAuth? and ive understood the  "me/home" would be to show the user's main page, is it possible to show my group's page or other pages for the matter from the "me/home" part?

Comment: Gentleman; so sorry! let me try again. following http://www.richardnichols.net/2010/06/implementing-facebook-oauth-2-0-authentication-in-java/ , can i implement the OAuth in the github's example of coding?

Comment: next, if what i need is like a shortcut to my group's page, do i still need the OAuth as the app will function will like a shortcut;

Comment: Lastly, the "me/home" would bring the user to their home page, so could i change that to accommodate my app that will bring a user straight to my group's page?

Comment: For your first question, the example is for web application only.

Comment: for every facebook request, you'll need to pass an `access_token`. I hope you read the link on Facebook Authentication (posted on my example). It shows you how do get access token from mobile devices

Comment: for the last question, read the Facebook Graph API. the "me/home" doesn't return you to the page, it returns a JSON response string. you'll have to see the Facebook Android SDK on how to do it.

Comment: Gentleman; thanx for clarifying my questions :D you've been of great help really! i'm back with another question hopefully it will be a while  before my next, but here goes; from the github example, there doesnt seem to be any of the client_secret and stuff like that, does that mean that from the example, the OAuth2.0 has not been included?

Comment: @eddy, the example of the Facebook API uses an old Facebook REST API (which had it's own authentication scheme). It even says `"Your Facebook Application ID must be set before running this example
    // See http://www.facebook.com/developers/createapp.php"`.

Comment: Gentleman; I think i have understood how the graph api works and what sort of connection or properties to use, but the example uses the graph api as they use the "me/home" phrase i've also figured out how to change the set of permissions that i need but, after the user allows my application, and I still can't figure out where do i change where the next screen will go, currently, it'd only go to my home page.

Comment: The same way they do a request to `me/home`, just change the `me/home` to an `id` for a specific page/group/etc.

Comment: so now i've changed from "me/home" to my "(mygroupid)/home" and from "me/feed" to "(mygroupid)/feed" but, after logging in, all i get is a blank screen. im pretty sure the StreamRenderer is ok so that leaves me with the other possible cause, could it be my token and my secret key and stuff? :(

Comment: The ones that's giving you problems.

Comment: from the StreamHandler; Facebook fb = Session.restore(getActivity()).getFb();
        new AsyncFacebookRunner(fb).request("(mygroupid)", 
                new StreamRequestListener());

Comment: from the StreamRendere i didn't edit anything, and i edited StreamJsHandler to the following;  public void updateStatus(final String message) {
        AsyncFacebookRunner fb = getFb();
        Bundle params = new Bundle();
        params.putString("message", message);
        fb.request("(mygroupid)/feed", params, "POST", new AsyncRequestListener()

Comment: Facebook returns a JSON object back, so what does `StreamRequestListener()` do with the response?

Comment: Ok, you are lost....read the Facebook Graph API for every graph. When you do a request to Facebook, it returns a JSON back. What you will have to do, is create a listener that will process that JSON response sent from Facebook Graph. That example given was how to update Facebook Status and the `RequestListener()` that handled the response. You can write a Listener that's an `Activity` to every Graph Object you're planning to request from Facebook. E.g `StatusActivity extends Activity implements SomeRequestListener` (example). I hope this is clear.

Comment: And you cannot request a Graph Object from Facebook without an `access_token`. Hence why you need to know how to Authenticate to Facebook.